# Check if element is being animated CSS3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

Is there any way to check if element is being animated?

But being animated **not** with jquery's animate, but with css3's transition..

The problem I have is... I have this slider, on arrow click I give it

```
left = left+200
```

where left is either

```
element.position().left
```

or

```
parseInt(element.css("left"));
```

(it doesn't really matter, the problem occurs with either)

the element is being animated with

```
transition: left 400ms ease-in-out;
```

so, when the user clicks on the arrow once and then again before the animation finishes, left returns value depending on its position(so instead of say.. 400px, it might return 235.47px since it was clicked in the middle of the animation)..

Comment: If you animate it to 400px, then doesn't 235.47px tell you it's being animated?

Comment: I don't animate it to 400px, I animate it to *current left* + 220px, how could I possibly check if it's already on *left after animation*, when I don't really know the *left after animation*..

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you change the `left` property of an element, you can associate a boolean value with it (using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for instance) and set it to `true` to indicate a transition has started. Then, you can bind to the [transition end event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition) (which varies depending on the browser) and set the boolean value back to `false` from your handler to indicate the transition has ended.

The end result is something like:

```
yourElement.on(
    "transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd",
    function() {
        $(this).data("transitioning", false);  // Transition has ended.
    }
);
```

(Note the code above only has to run once.)

---

```
if (!yourElement.data("transitioning")) {
    // No transition active, compute new position.
    var theNewLeft = yourElement.position().left + 200;
    // Set new position, which will start a new transition.
    yourElement.data("transitioning", true).css("left", theNewLeft);
}
```