# Is there a way to tell if an element has completed a CSS3 transition?

Tags: javascript, events, css

I'm looking for an event, callback or other way to tell when a CSS3 transition completes.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736919/check-if-element-is-being-animated-css3 might help

Comment: Thanks, that answers a slightly different question -- in progress vs. completed -- but is also helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition) event. Note that vendor-specific prefixes have to be added.

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the transitionend event:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_completion_of_a_transition

Since it uses browser prefixes, you'll have to listen to several different versions of that event for different browsers.