# Jquery .click wait until transition ends

Tags: jquery

does anyone know how to stop a .click function from working if the element is currently rotating.

```
$(".right").click(function(e) {

  angle1 = getRotationDegrees($('.circle'));//find current rotation angle
  newrot = angle1-90;//take 90 degrees from current rotation

  if($('.circle').is(':animated')) return;

  $('.circle').transition({ rotate: newrot+'deg',
    duration: 500  });   
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736919/check-if-element-is-being-animated-css3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unbind the event when the element is rotating with this:

```
$(".right").unbind( "click" );
```

If the element finish rotating you bind the click event again.

Comment: How would i restructure this using bind and unbind ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this could be to check if `currentAngle % 90 == 0` before doing the **transition** again.

I think the problem why `:animated` isn't working is because `transition (css)` is not the same as `jQuery animations`, and therefore `:animated` is NOT carried by transitions.