# Check if element has css animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script that removes an element when a css3 animation triggers `AnimationEnd` in jQuery. The problem is that these animations are bound to an external css file that may not be included.

Right now I call this.

```
$element.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(event) {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

But if the element does not have the animation because either the browser didn't support it or the animation file was not included I still need to remove the element. How can I check if this was called.

I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to change the value to true.

```
var hasAnimation = false;
$element.one('webkitAnimationStart oanimationstart msAnimationStart animationstart', function(event) {
        hasAnimation = true;
});
if (!hasAnimation) {
        $element.remove();
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736919/check-if-element-is-being-animated-css3

Comment: I found that, the problem is that I am not sure how to convert that answer into something I can use. The answer their is assuming the animation will always start. I am trying to check and see if the animation can start.

Comment: at least you should give javascript a chance to trigger animation start ... I think if you put: "if has animation" in a setTimeout-function 5ms? should do the trick

Comment: @halfbit So this worked. I would have liked to avoided a `setTimeout` but hey, gotta do what you gotta do.

Comment: the setTimeout isnt so bad it should even work with '0', I try to make an answer and a more detailed explananation iut of this ..

Comment: setTimeout isn't bad, I just personally prefer to avoid them if 
I can. haha. I'll mark your answer as the answer then.

Comment: I think about setTimeout(f,0,x) not as timeout, its more a "ImedaiateReEnqueue(f,x)" function for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You checking the the `hasAnimation` before the animation started, because you did not give up your 'timeslice'. (thats the wrong terminology, but I think 'timeslice' just describes whats going on)

AFAIK no Javascript implementaion is - preemtive - multithreaded, at least not at script level. So if you loop, you loop, and nothing else happens.

Imagine events like putting functions on a queue, and these are fired/called one after the other. Well behaved. So if you want to know whats the result of such an event, you have to end your current function (call it giving up the timeslice). Now the event starts - and is the only one now.

So if you enqueue your `cleanup_if_no_animation( hasAnimation )` with a `setTimeout(0)` you dont really play around with times as long as the `StartAnimation` is not triggert with a `setTimeout` itself, you just give up, and start again after the (optional start event)

The same situation you have, if you want to cout to 1000 and put this into a DIV. you must use setTimeout(0) between the steps to get the display updated.

like in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/hjMv8/)

```
function bad_loop() {
    for (i = 1; i < 100; ++i) {
        $('#out').text(i)
    } }

function good_loop(i = 1) { 
    $('#out').text(i)
    if (i<50) setTimeout(good_loop,0,i+1) }
```